# How to send an email to an O365 Group as a different user with Graph API?

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, office365

I want to send an email to an Office365 Group using Graph API. My issue is that all the emails are sent from the user I am using to generate the token. This is expected as the API endpoint only supports User tokens (Delegated permissions) as described here.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/conversation-post-threads?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp

Is there any way I can use Graph API to send an email to an O365 Group as another user? I know this is possible when sending an email to a regular user (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-send-mail-from-other-user), but not sure how to do it with O365 Groups.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is not possible, unfortunately. You have to use EWS.